# How to avoid resetting the whole view after loading an imageview in Android?

Tags: android, imageview

I'm working on an Android project with a lot image loading from a remote server.

I'm using this utility for downloading the images:

http://code.google.com/p/android-imagedownloader/

The main issue is when any image download finishes, the whole Screen would seem to reset.

Along with the view reset the position of the animated UI controls resets too.

Answer (score 0):

That code is based on an article from two years ago and the Android Developers have since given much better information and methods for handling ASync images within a ListView Adaptewr.

Ideally you should be implementing an ImageDownload class or some sorts and using the `notifyDataSetChanged();` call on your `ListViewAdpater` to have the View updated correctly.

**Create an ImageLoadedCallback:**

```
// Interfaces
public interface ImageLoadedCallback {
  public void imageLoaded(Drawable imageDrawable, String imageUrl);
}
```

**Implement it on your ListAdapter:**

All this code is doing is getting the next item to display in the List and then looking to see if we have the image available, if we do - set it. If not, send away our ASync request to load it and then let the Adapter know that it's ready.

```
public class ArticleAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter implements ImageLoadedCallback {
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(getCursor().moveToPosition(position)) {
      ViewHolder viewHolder;

      if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_list_item, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgArticleImage);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
      } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
      }
      String image = getCursor().getString(getCursor().getColumnIndex("thumbURL"));
      if(imgCache.hasImage(image)) {
        viewHolder.image.setImageDrawable(imgCache.loadDrawable(image, this));
      } else {
       imgCache.loadDrawable(image, this);
      }
    }
    return convertView;
  }

  public void imageLoaded(Drawable imageDrawable, String imageUrl) {
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
}
```